# How do I use databases within ASP.Net

Tags: mysql, asp.net, oledb

I've developed web applications in PHP for a few years and would like to learn about ASP.Net. I've installed VS2013 and have created an ASP.Net Web Application. I tried playing around with something that I found on *wait for it* W3Schools just because I knew it would be as simple as simple could be but it caused me some errors. I was trying to "connect" to an Access file in the wwwroot directory by using System.Data.OleDb but I had some problems.

My question is: Is there a simplistic way like in PHP where you have PHPMyAdmin to manage the database and then connect via something simple like $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db'); but for ASP.Net?

I'm struggling to find beginner level support for this on the web and would like to figure it out asap!

Comment: what about a little search effort on youtube?

Comment: Could you show your markup and connection code?  It's hard to guess at what your problem is based on the given information.

Answer (score 2):

David, isnt's going to be "simple" as PHP, remember that VS2013 it's a server side language, more strong and complex.
I recommend to you the next:
Work with objects.
Here is some code may help you.

C#:

```
public System.Data.DataSet GetQuery(string _QueryComm){
System.Data.DataSet objResult = new System.Data.DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter;

strProvider = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=Database;User Id=databaseuser;Password=pass;";
objCon = new OleDbConnection(strProvider);
objCon.Open();
try
{
    objAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(_QueryComm, objCon);
    objAdapter.Fill(objResult);
    objAdapter.Dispose();
    objCon.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Some exception handler
}
return objResult;}
```

Usage:

```
DataSet datainfo = GetQuery("select * from table");
```

VB:

```
Public Function GetQuery(strCommandQuery as String) As System.Data.DataSet
Dim objResult As System.Data.DataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
Dim objAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter

strProvider = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=Database;User Id=databaseuser;Password=pass;"

objCon = New OleDbConnection(strProvider)
objCon.Open()

Try
    objAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(strCommandQuery, objCon)
    objAdapter.Fill(objResult)
    objAdapter.Dispose()
    objCon.Close()
Catch ex As System.Exception
    ' Some exception handler
End Try

Return objResult  End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim datainfo as DataSet = GetQuery("select * From table")
```

Let me know if it's work for you.